# XPages - extlib 9.0.1v12 and JQuery 2.11

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I have always used in my projects the latest version of the extension library for 9.01v12 9.0.1fp3 Domino

Everything works properly and well . But in this scenario, I have a large number of clients , with the terrible IE8 browser :-(

The problem is that JQuery 2.x broke support IE8 and I see errors in the code JS code JQuery .

If I try to manually put the 1.X version of JQuery everything works properly .

But the problem is that I use version EXTLIB bootstrap right now and everything is calculated and drawn on in runtime .

Do you have ideas ?
It would be enough to actually enter the following syntax in nell'extlib bootstrap Theme (upload too the JQuery 1.11.3), but I don't know how.

```
<resource rendered="#{javascript:context.getUserAgent().isIE(0,8)}">
     <content-type>application/x-javascript</content-type>
     <href>/.ibmxspres/.extlib/responsive/jquery/jquery-1.11.3.min.js</href>
    </resource>
```

Some suggest ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you already said JQuery 2.x drops support for IE 8 and lower. To support IE 8 and lower, you will have to use jQuery 1.x.

I think you will have to load Bootstrap manually, and won't be able to take advantage of the latest ExtLib with built in Bootstrap. When I say manually, I mean before the latest ExtLib, the way you used to do it. You can still use the Bootstrap4Xpages openNTF project if you like, as it uses jQuery 1.11 and Bootstrap 3.2.

I wouldn't recommend using both jQuery versions in the same application. But with that being said, you asked if you can try loading the old jQuery for IE8 only. I would say that it is worth a try, but I would be surprised if everything just worked in new and old browsers.

I would also recommend storing your bootstrap code in your NSF as a resource if you are not already.

If you are forced to use bootstrap with IE 8, there will be cool things that you just won't be able to do. This was true even with version 2.3 of Bootstrap. As someone who has to support IE 8, I feel your pain.

**The bottom line is that I think you are stuck doing this the old way.**

Comment: Yes i know... My problemi is that the native bootstrap theme transform inputbox, calendar picker.. Without any rows of code... Now is need to re-engineering my project :-(

Comment: I have resolve manually..with a reverse engine of extlib...recreate a thema from zero...with bootstrap and js resouce into webcontent